# Formatting a card expiry date validator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, tkinter, formatting

### **Hello community!**

I have quite a problem with my python code, I have been trying to resolve it for days, but I can't make it work. I am working on an online shopping service for my school's assignment. I am trying to create a credit card validator. What my problem concerns is that when I have an entry for user to put his expiry date, I am trying to format it in this way **MM/YY** so for instance 01/20 or 11/23 . I am trying to make it automatically add the / slash. So that when user inputs 12 it will automatically add the `/`

So far I am tracking when there is a change in the entry box, so it knows when to add the slash. I have unfortunately problem with formatting. So when the input is `12/21` and the users deletes the first "2" char, the input becomes this:

[image]

While debbuing I sometimes can see these results:

[image]

Or such:

[image]

Here is the code I use. Do you see any mistake or is there an efficient way to do so?

```py
def validateDate():
    global entryDateCard,dateCard    ##entryDateCard is just Entry ID, dateCard is the expiry date
    print("bbb")

    if (len(entryDateCard.get())==5):
        print("ccc")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard)
    dateCard = entryDateCard.get()

    if (2<=len(entryDateCard.get())<=4 and (entryDateCard.get().find("/")!=2)):  ## does not work even when true
        print("aaa")
        dateCard.replace("/","")
        entryDateCard.delete(0,"end")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard)
        entryDateCard.insert(2,"/")

    if(len(entryDateCard.get())>5):
        entryDateCard.delete(0,"end")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard[:5])
        dateCard = dateCard[:5]
```

EDIT1 : Tried this but still does not work (Posting an entire snippet of code)

```py
import tkinter
w = 1280
h = 720
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=w,height=h,bg="#71CAE7")
canvas.pack()


entryDateCard=0
dateCard=""


cardDateSV=tkinter.StringVar()
cardDateSV.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=cardDateSV: validateDate())
entryDateCard = tkinter.Entry(width=15,font = "Helvetica 15 bold",textvariable=cardDateSV)
entryDateCard.pack()
entryDateCard.place(x=(w//2)-275,y=h-(0.61*h),height=30)


def validateDate():
    global entryDateCard,dateCard
    dateCard = entryDateCard.get()
    if (len(dateCard.replace("/",""))==2):
        entryDateCard.insert(2,"/")
        print("two")
    elif (len(dateCard.replace("/",""))==3):
        entryDateCard.delete(0,"end")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard[:2])
        entryDateCard.insert(2,"/")
        entryDateCard.insert(3,dateCard[3:4])
        print("three")
    elif (len(dateCard.replace("/",""))==4):
        entryDateCard.delete(0,"end")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard[:2])
        entryDateCard.insert(2,"/")
        entryDateCard.insert(3,dateCard[3:5])
        print("four")
    elif (len(dateCard.replace("/",""))>=5):
        print("max")
        entryDateCard.delete(0,"end")
        entryDateCard.insert(0,dateCard[:5])
        dateCard = dateCard[:5]
```

Comment: (1) If "entryDateCard" is just an ID why do you check it for a slash and later insert a slash. I guess that it actually represents the input field in some GUI (which one)?) (2) If "dateCard" is a string be aware that "replace" returns a new string and doesn't modify the existing one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for  your comment. Yes, I am using tkinter and entryDateCard represents the input field.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried to change the code a little bit, but still didn't make it to work when I debug. I edited the question and posted an edit there so you can copy it and try it by yourself

Comment: Means "doesn't work" the same as before? If not you should update/append the description of the behavior.

Comment: One thing I see already is that your code makes assumptions where the slash (if any at all) is in the string (when using slices like "dateCard[3:4]").